# SilverStripe duplicate entries even with unique index

Tags: sql, orm, silverstripe

I'm trying to prevent duplicate records when adding customer records in my CRM with the following index:

```
private static $indexes = array(
    'IndexFirstSurName' => array(
        'type' => 'unique', 
        'value' => '"FirstName","Surname"'
    )
);
```

Note that I extended `Customer` from `Member` where `FirstName` and `Surname` came from:

```
class Customer extends Member
```

But SilverStripe is still allowing duplicate entries of `FirstName` and `Surname` combination?  Has anyone experienced the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Man, in my experience a validate() is still needed even when using indexing:

```
public function validate() {
    $result = parent::validate();

    if(Member::get()->filter(array('FirstName' => $this->FirstName, 'Surname' => $this->Surname))->first()) {
        $result->error('First and Surname must be unique for each member.');
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Alternately for a more robust breakout:

```
public function validate() {
    $result = parent::validate();

    if($member = Member::get()->filter(array('FirstName' => $this->FirstName, 'Surname' => $this->Surname))->first()) {
        if($member->FirstName == $this->FirstName){
            $result->error('Your Surname is fine, please change your First Name.');
        }
        if($member->Surname == $this->Surname){
            $result->error('Your First Name is fine, please change your Surname.');
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: this is a good way to validate fields but I think Silverstripe unique index is rendered useless.

Comment: @muskie9 - shouldn't that be a validate error and mention the field specifically.... so that the error appears next to that field?

Comment: @Barry yes, additional logic could be done to determine the exact field, but this would be the minimum to ensure no other records share the FirstName/Surname values.

Comment: how do one determine the exact field and make the error appear next to that field?

Answer (score 2):

> note that I extended Customer from Member were FirstName and Surname came from

I wonder if SilverStripe is attempting to set indexes on the non-existent fields `Customer.FirstName` and `Customer.Surname`. Maybe try qualifying the columns by prepending the table that is *actually* having the indexes added to it like this:

```
private static $indexes = array(
    'IndexFirstSurName' => array(
        'type' => 'unique', 
        'value' => '"Member"."FirstName","Member"."Surname"'
    )
);
```

You might also consider *decorating* `Member` instead of subclassing it. That way you wouldn't need to qualify the query fragments in this way.

Answer (score 2):

The way to extend `Member` on SilverStripe is by extending `DataExtension`. As theruss is saying, you are trying to create a unique index on the table `Customer`, where you prabably do not have the fields `FirstName` and `Surname`.
Try this instead

```
class Customer extends DataExtension
{
    private static $indexes = array(
        'IndexFirstSurName' => array(
            'type' => 'unique', 
            'value' => '"FirstName","Surname"'
        )
    );
}
```

And then let SilverStripe know about your extension in `config.yml`

```
Member:
  extensions:
    - Customer
```

Now run `/dev/build?flush` and you should see your index being created.

Check [here](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/extending/extensions/) for more information about extensions.